# How to grep a string that exists only within a certain number of spaces of a line

Tags: sed, grep

How do I grep for a string within the first 36 spaces of a line?

I am having trouble grepping for a string of numbers (ex. "47225" or "82115") in a line. I know this number might actually occur twice within a line but I know that I only want the information in the line if it contains this number within the first 36 spaces. Unfortunately its not separated by columns because there might be other numbers in this particular column preceding or proceeding the string of numbers.

I have tried grepping " 47225" and "  47225" but this doesn't help the fact that there could be the same string existing after the first 36 spaces. Can I use sed or aux? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
grep -E '^.{0,31}(47225|82115)' file
```

`^.{0,31}` matches zero to 31 characters.  `(47225|82115)` matches either of the five digit numbers that you want.  Because 5+31=36, this assures that 47225 or 82115 are only matched if they occur within the first 36 characters of the line.

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
keep...........................47225
keep...........................82115
ignore..........................47225
ignore..........................82115
```

The first two lines above are 36 characters long and should match.  The last two lines above are 37 characters long and, thus, should be ignored.

Our command returns:

```
$ grep -E '^.{0,31}(47225|82115)' file
keep...........................47225
keep...........................82115
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
cut -c-36 file | grep -E '47225|82115'
```

I guess that by *spaces*, you mean *characters positions*...

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'h;s/^(.{36}).*/\1/;/pattern1|pattern2/!d;x' file
```

Make a copy of the line, remove everything after character 36, pattern match and if not found delete otherwise reinstate the original line.